# Crash with a ListView in a LinearLayout in a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, slidingmenu

When I put a `LinearLayout` as parent of a `ListView` in `DrawerLayout` I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```

For example:

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **layout_gravity** for LinearLayout

```
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i copied answered xml but i am getting error like  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: full code means which i have already mentioned xml file. if i remove DrawerLinear  Linear Layout which is parent of listview then i am not getting error but i want to put this layout as a parent of listview because want to show profile pic and name which should not scroll

Answer (score 0):

You have to group them in the drawer layout and set the gravity property to the linear layout to treat it as the drawer content:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DrawerLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```